# Toggle Slide-Over out of Visibility on Browser Window Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have added this feature to my website, [Jquery-Slide-Over](https://github.com/jme783/slide-over), however when I toggle the slide-over [on then off], it remains visible when I resize the browser window. How do I stop this? Thanks.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 641.008px) {
  .slide-over {
    width: 90%;
    right: -90%;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
  }
  .slide-over.left {
    right: auto;
    left: -90%;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
  }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025.008px) {
  .slide-over {
    width: 80%;
    right: -80%;
  }
  .slide-over.left {
    right: auto;
    left: -80%;
  }

}
```

```js
$('body').append(
        "<div class='slide-over'>"
      + "<a href='#' data-slideover='close' class='close-x'><span class='icon-cross'></span></a>"
      + "</div>"
      + "<div class='overlay0' data-slideover='close'>"
      + "</div>"
    );
```

Comment: It must add some style in your html tag. Try putting **!important** in your css. Ex. **left: -80% !important;**

Comment: The plugin works fine, if I on and off the slideover and then resize the browser the slide over is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
right: (settings.orientation == 'right' ? -(panelWidth*2) : "auto"),
 left: (settings.orientation == 'left' ? -(panelWidth*2) : "auto")
```

Figured it out